# Batch file to report empty folders and exclude hidden files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I found this code to find and report all empty folders.

```
@echo off
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (
  dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
```

This works exactly as expected, however some of the folders have the hidden file "thumbs.db" and are not being reported as empty.  I do not have permissions on the server to delete the hidden files so that the folders are actually empty.  Is there a way to modify the above code to exclude hidden files or a single file by name?

Comment: The folders are not being reported as empty with the hidden file, so it is working correctly.  The problem is I can't delete the hidden file to make it actually empty so it's reported. I use the script to tell me what's empty and missing information.  When it finds the thumbs.db folder and doesn't report the folder as empty I don't know unless I check.  Which is what the point of the script was in the first place to make it so I don't have to manually check the folders.

Comment: I am looking to modify this code to assist in one hiccup that appears.  Sometimes when I add files to the folders it's not all at the same time and they may come on separate dates.  So when I add in the files I get today, knowing there are more coming in the future, this scripts doesn't report the folder as empty because it's not.

Is it possible to modify this to check for a specific file in the folder say "PENDING" and still report it as empty?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (
  dir /a:-h /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
```